How wild is the maximal ideal space of the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra of the real line?
The Fourier-Stieltjes algebra of $\mathbb R$ is the set of all sufficiently nice measures on $\mathbb R$. The vector product is convolution of measures. By identifying each measure with its Fourier transform we can treat the algebra as the space $F$ of functions of the form
$$x \mapsto \int e^{-i \lambda x} d \mu(\lambda)$$
as $\mu$ ranges over the set of allowed measures.
The maximal ideal space is the set of all multiplicative linear functionals $F \to \mathbb C$. One simple class of functionals are obtained by taking a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ and sending
$$\int e^{-i \lambda x} d \mu(\lambda) \mapsto \int \phi(-\lambda) d \mu (\lambda)$$
It is straightforward to see this functional is linear. It is well-defined because the Fourier transform is invertible. To see the function is multiplicative we must check
$$\left ( \int e^{-i \lambda x} d \mu(\lambda)\right) \left( \int e^{-i \lambda' x} d \nu(\lambda')\right) $$ $$ = \int \int e^{-i (\lambda+\lambda') x} d \mu(\lambda)  d \nu(\lambda')  $$
$$  =  \int e^{-i \lambda  x} d (\mu*\nu)(\lambda)   \mapsto   \int \phi(-\lambda) d (\mu*\nu)(\lambda) $$
$$  =  \int \int \phi(-(\lambda+\lambda')) d \mu(\lambda) d \nu (\lambda') $$ $$=  \int \int \phi(-\lambda) \phi(-\lambda') d \mu(\lambda) d \nu (\lambda')$$
$$  =   \int \phi(-\lambda)   d \mu(\lambda)  \int \phi(-\lambda') d \nu(\lambda')  $$
However this seems to be demanding more of the functional than the definition of linearity requires. Linearity demands the functional commute with finite linear combinations. But the above object commutes  $\phi$ with integrals which is much stronger.
I suspect the maximal ideal space is vast and pathological. What is the next most complex bunch of functionals we can construct?

This is not an answer, but you may be able to track down some references in the literature if you search for articles on the maximal ideal space of the convolution algebra M(R), which is of course isomorphic to the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra of R via the Fourier transform. In particular, see the references mentioned in the first paragraph of J. L. Taylor's Acta Math 1971 article (DOI: 10.1007/BF02392031)

(I see that you have defined the FS algebra of R as its measure algebra, this is not quite right. The FS algebra is defined to consist of the linear span of positive-definite continuous functions on the group, and then Bochner's theorem tells us that the FS algebra of a LCA group G coincides with the measure algebra of the dual group G-hat.)
